# Api Platform - Symfony - return json in a persist fuction

Tags: php, symfony

I needd to return a JsonResponse inside persist fuction.

this is an example of my DataPersister class, the goal it's return a JsonResponse, when i try, i get the error: The controller must return a \"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response\" object but it returned an object of type App\Entity\VerificationCodes.

```php
<?php
// api/src/DataPersister/UsersDataPersister.php

namespace App\DataPersister;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface;
use App\Entity\Users;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

final class UsersDataPersister implements DataPersisterInterface 
{    
    private $managerRegistry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
      $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }


    public function supports($data): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Users;
    }

    public function persist($data){
        $em = $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass(Users::class);
        $user = new Users();
        //Persist User with encode password
        return $user;
        return new JsonResponse(['response'=>'yes']);
    }


    public function remove($data)
    {
      throw new \RuntimeException('"remove" is not supported');
    }
}
```

please help me or tell me what i can do, than you

Answer (score 2):

If you want that `App\Entity\Users` class will be converted into a JSON you can implement `JsonSerializable` inferface (is PHP native interface). This interface force you to implement the method `jsonSerialized` that is automatically called when the object is converted to json (for example when you use `json_encode($user);`.

Finally you can try with

```
class Users implements \JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return []; // an array representation of your class
    }
}
```

then you can ...

```
return new JsonResponse(json_encode($user));
```

or (maybe) ...

```
return new JsonResponse($user);
```